# Field List "exists()" incorrect

Tags: apache, solr

Solr 4.2.1

It seems no matter what I try I can't get correct results out of the exists() function. I am using it to check if a field of type "text_general" exists in the schema. It works somewhat, however ~10% of the time it's wrong.

Here is the simplified code I am using in the FL portion of the query to test it.

```
fl=list:if(exists(title),1,0),title
```

Here is a sample record I get which is incorrect.

```
<str name="title">Tonight Tonight</str> #Obviously exists
<long name="list">0</long></doc> #Still returns 0
```

Here is my schema definition, maybe text_general has problems with this? I can't find anything in the docs about it.

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the field exists or not check for [Negative queries](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser).

```
-field:[* TO *] finds all documents without a value for field
```

You can also try `-field:["" TO *]`

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it won't work in a boolean functional query. Meaning I can't use that as a check in an if statement.

Comment: do you want to return the value ?

Comment: Yes, I was just using 1 and 0 to point out its brokenness. The full query will look more like

`fl=list:if(exists(title),title,somethingElse),title`

Edit: I've actually worked around this issue by having my MySQL import query to do the check for me and assign the appropriate value. I am still curious as to why this doesn't work though.

Comment: This might be a bug, the behavior just seems very inconsistent.